# Assign data with method to vue data variable dynamic

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I assign data to a dynamic variable.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

My vue data variable:

```
test: '',
```

Adding a click

```
<div @click="assignData(test)"
```

Method:

```
assignData(value) {
   // Now I don't want this
   this.test = 'lorem..';

   // Instead I want something like this
  value = 'new value for test';

  // Or
  this.value = 'new value for test';
}
```

Now obviously this is not gonna work, but I hope you'll get the idea.

I need to change many variables and I don't want to add all the variables in the function like this

```
assignData(value) {

   this.test = 'lorem..';
   this.anotherVar = 'ipsum';
   this.newTest = '....';       
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could send the property you want to change with the function.

```
<div @click="assignData('test', 'new value for test)">
```

and then in your code

```
 assignData(prop,val) {
        this[prop] = val;
      console.log(this.test);
    }
```

Here is a snippet from jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/6447/

Comment: How does that work when I want to target a key in an object? Example: `assignData('test.user.name', 'new value for name)`

Comment: This code won't work for that. You would need to modify it. Is there a reason you don't want to use multiple functions one for each object? For example updateUser - updateCar - updateHome and have explicit statements what is mapped to what.

Comment: Also where are you getting the values? From an input or http request or? If its inputs, then v-model might be the solution you are looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/6453/

Comment: I need to assign Pixi objects everytime I click depending on the value. But I guess It can't be shortened.

Answer (score 3):

```js
assignData(key, value) {
  this[key] = value;
}
```

You'll have to specify the variable you're assigning when you activate it with the click caller.

Answer (score 2):

You should use either `vm.$set( target, key, value )` or `Vue.set( target, key, value )`

[Vue.set docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

[vm.$set docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)